# Eval javascript object using jint

Tags: javascript, .net, jint

I'm using jint to parse javascript code, the following js codes work:

- `1`
- `[1]`
- `{}`

but this one fails:

`{ a: 1}`

with this error:

> `int.Parser.ParserException: Line 1: Unexpected token :
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ThrowError(Token token, String messageFormat, Object[] arguments)
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ThrowUnexpected(Token token)
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ConsumeSemicolon()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseStatement()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseStatement()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseSourceElement()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseStatementList()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseBlock()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseStatement()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseSourceElement()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseSourceElements()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseProgram()
>      at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.Parse(String code, ParserOptions options)
>      at Jint.Engine.Execute(String source)`

I don't want to deserialize a JSON file, I want to execute a javascript object, I'd like to have something like:

```
{
  id: 'one',
  code: function() { console.log('hello'); }
}
```

I noticed that if I do this:

```
var x = {a: 1}
x
```

then it works, but I need it to be a javascript object in my scenario.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It probably interprets it as a block rather than an object literal. Try to wrap it in parenthesis, i.e. `({ a: 1 })`

Comment: It works! thank you!

Comment: Can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Alright! I'll add it as a proper answer so that you can resolve this question.

Comment: not sure why you want that format to begin with since you can't really reference the methods/properties in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ a: 1}` gets interpreted as a block statement rather than an object literal. The solution is to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
({ a: 1 })
```